# Passport Facebook Not Working with React Application

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js, webpack-dev-server

When i am trying to implement authentication using Passport Facebook Strategy, It showing an error in console, **the error is showing below:**

refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/auth/dist/bundle.js' because its mime type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict mime type checking is enabled.

Comment: How does the implementation look like?

Comment: what type of looks you are asking abt

Comment: I mean the code to reproduce the issue